# How to stop lizards entering through windows

Tags: home, pest-control

The very sight of lizards makes me take a stick and drive them out of the windows. I heard if we place egg shells near the windows they repel. But is there any other way we could accomplish this? Due to this, I have most of my windows closed..

Comment: window screens?

Comment: Through Windows, exhaust vents,  etc  @bluet

Comment: @sairam01 Did you try the egg shell idea? Also, as bluet suggests, screens would be a standard solution - can you explain if you've tried that or why it's not appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a method my mother has used for quite some time. And it works.

Take an egg, break it. Remove everything inside till you have just the shell.

Fix a small iron nail on the wall and hang the shell on that nail.

I have observed that lizards want to stay as far as they can from this particular contraption.

Comment: Is this for real?

Comment: Apparently the theory is that lizards associate eggshells with other creatures -  possible predators - so they stay away.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to make a lizard door. Failing that, you could could seal all gaps. In my opinion though the best way to deal with the problem would be to work on your tolerance of lizards. I did this (spiders, snakes and lizards) through spending time in lizard country. Once I got over their presence I then had to deal with lizard excrement raining from the ceiling onto my bed and everything else.

Comment: A lizard door?  So they will use the door instead of the window?  Really!